# How do I create a row combining certain values of previous rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

In my data, I have some lines that represent results from a repeated test. Only certain values are captured in the repeat. What I'd like to do is to create a new row with the repeat values but pulling from the initial test if the repeat values are NA or blank.

E.g. for,

```
Patient ID   Initial/Repeat   Value    Value 2   Accept/Reject
A1                   Initial      95        NA          Reject
A1                    Repeat      NA        80          Accept    
A2                   Initial      80        70          Accept
```

I'd like to tranform into:

```
Patient ID   Initial/Repeat   Value    Value 2   Accept/Reject
A1                    Repeat      95        80          Accept    
A2                   Initial      80        70          Accept
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(zoo)
require(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Patient_ID) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE))) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   Patient_ID [2]
  Patient_ID Initial_Repeat Value Value2 Accept_Reject
       <chr>          <chr> <int>  <int>         <chr>
1         A1         Repeat    95     80        Accept
2         A2        Initial    80     70        Accept
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it always a series of NA's with a single valid value?  If yes, you could take the mean of the rows, throwing away any NA's.  I do this using `dplyr`'s grouping and summarising functionality:

```
# Sample data:
df = read.table(text="PatientID   Initial_Repeat   Value    Value2   Accept_Reject
A1                   Initial      95        NA          Reject
A1                    Repeat      NA        80          Accept    
A2                   Initial      80        70          Accept", header = TRUE)

# My solution uses the dplyr package:
library(dplyr)
answer = df %>% 
     group_by(PatientID) %>% 
     summarise(Value = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE), Value2 = mean(Value2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

answer:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  PatientID Value Value2
     <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1        A1    95     80
2        A2    80     70
```

> 

Comment: It's most commonly 2 rows, but could be more.

Comment: When it's multiple rows, is it a series of NA until it hits a correct answer?  If yes, then `mean` with `na.rm = TRUE` (as I've done it) might work best.  Try it.

Comment: I think so, but I'll have to get more information about the data. (I recently started at this position).

Comment: Apparently there are a few cases where there are multiple data in the columns and not just NAs.

Comment: In that case, neither my answer nor Ryan Runge's are the correct ones.  chan1142 gives you the answer which selects the FIRST instance of a successful value.

Answer (score 1):

Without extra libraries:

```
df1 <- with(df, data.frame(PatientID=tapply(PatientID, PatientID, 
    function(x) x[length(x)])))
df1$Inital_Repeat <- with(df, tapply(Initial_Repeat, PatientID, 
    function(x) levels(Initial_Repeat)[x[length(x)]]))
for (v in c('Value', 'Value2')) 
    df1[[v]] <- tapply(df[[v]], df$PatientID, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])
df1$Accept_Reject <- with(df, tapply(Accept_Reject, PatientID,
    function(x) levels(Accept_Reject)[x[length(x)]]))
```

Output:

```
   PatientID Inital_Repeat Value Value2 Accept_Reject
A1         1        Repeat    95     80        Accept
A2         2       Initial    80     70        Accept
```

Note that `Inital_Repeat` and `Accept_Reject` are `factor`s.

EDIT: `PatientID` is also a `factor`, which is why we have `1` and `2` for `PatientID`. To have "A1" and "A2", change `x[length(x)]` on line 2 to `levels(x)[x[length(x)]]`. Also, `levels(Initial_Repeat)` on line 4 can be replaced with `levels(x)`, so can `levels(Accept_Reject)` on line 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found tools within the `tidyverse` also accomplish the job. It's a little slower than `zoo` but offers better readability and requires fewer packages to be loaded.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Patient_ID) %>%
  fill(names(df), .direction = "down") %>%
  filter(row_number() == n())
```